# How to use macro variable in datalines?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
%let stmDate = 05FEB2017;
%let stmDueDate = %sysfunc(intnx(day,"&stmDate"d,20),date9.);

data header;
    input  statement_date date7.
         statement_due_date date7.;
    format statement_date date7.
         statement_due_date date7.;
    datalines;
    &stmDate &stmDueDate
run;
```

How can I resolve the macro variable within the datalines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS will not expand macro code in `DATALINES`. Note that there is no need in your example program. Just use the macro variables to generate the code needed to set your dataset variables.

```
data header;
  statement_date = "&stmDate"d;
  statement_due_date = "&stmDueDate"d ;
  format statement_date statement_due_date date9.;
run;
```

But if you did want to do this then take a look at `PROC STREAM` to convert the resolved lines into a file and then read from that file.

So create your macro variables.

```
%let stmDate = 05FEB2017;
%let stmDueDate = %sysfunc(intnx(day,"&stmDate"d,20),date9.);
```

Then use PROC STREAM to convert them into a data file. You could even have you macro function call.

```
filename text temp;

proc stream outfile=text; begin
&stmDate &stmDueDate
&stmDate %sysfunc(intnx(day,"&stmDate"d,20),date9.)
;;;;
```

Then read from the generated file.  In general it will remove the line breaks so you might want to use `@@` in your INPUT statement.

```
data header;
  infile text ;
  input statement_date statement_due_date @@ ;
  format _numeric_ date9.;
  informat _numeric_ date9.;
run;
```