# How can I store a macro variable value into SAS dataset?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need to store ​​macro variable values ​​in the SAS dataset like this:

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT SUM(Invoice)/1000 FORMAT COMMAX18.2 INTO :val01 FROM SASHELP.CARS;
QUIT;
%PUT &val01.;

PROC SQL;
    SELECT COUNT(Model) FORMAT COMMAX12. INTO :val02 FROM SASHELP.CARS;
QUIT;
%PUT &val02.;

PROC SQL;
    SELECT SUM(MSRP)/1000000 FORMAT COMMAX18.2 INTO :val03 FROM SASHELP.CARS;
QUIT;
%PUT &val03.;

data WORK.teste;
   input col01 $ col02 $ col03 $;
   datalines;
Invoice &val01.  k
Model   &val02.  un
MSRP    &val03.  mi
;


proc print data=WORK.teste;
run;
```

The desired result would be:

```
Obs  col01    col02      col03
1    Invoice  12.846,29  k
2    Model    428        un
3    MSRP     14,03      mi
```

However, ​​macro variable references are not being interpreted by SAS as ​​macro variable values.

And the result is:

```
Obs  col01    col02    col03
1    Invoice  &val01.  k
2    Model    &val02.  un
3    MSRP     &val03.  mi
```

How to make the SAS understand `&val01.` as a macro variable name, rather than a string.

Anyone would like a tip, please.

Comment: Why are you putting the values into macro variables if you actually need them in a dataset? Just leave the values in datasets.

Comment: I used the SASHELP.CARS table to illustrate my question. But the problem I want to solve is more complex. Your answer using RESOLVE() was perfect to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can could use the RESOLVE() function, as long as the lines of data are shorter than the maximum length allowed for a character variable.

```
%let val01= 12.846,29;
%let val02= 428;
%let val03= 14,03 ;

data test;
  input @;
  _infile_=resolve(_infile_);
  input col01 $ col02 $ col03 $;
datalines;
Invoice &val01.  k
Model   &val02.  un
MSRP    &val03.  mi
;
```

Or if it is only COL02 that needs to be replaced by the value of a macro variable then have the source data for that column just be the NAME of the macro variable, not an actual macro expression.  Then use the SYMGET() function to retrieve the value of the macro variable.

```
data test;
  length col01-col03 $10;
  input col01 mvar :$32. col03 ;
  col02 = symget(mvar);
  drop mvar;
datalines;
Invoice val01  k
Model   val02  un
MSRP    val03  mi
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Macro facility does not accept CARDS or PARMCARDS statements. See  https://support.sas.com/kb/43/902.html

And if you really want to do this, here are examples using different ways(`quote()` function or `proc stream`): https://support.sas.com/kb/43/295.html
[How to use macro variable in datalines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685255/how-to-use-macro-variable-in-datalines)

On the other hand, using `cards` statement is not valid in macro definition. See
https://technologytales.com/2008/10/28/sas-macro-and-datalinecards-statements-in-data-step/

The anwser about this question is from the first link, I copied it and write here:

> Most of the SAS Language and all of the SAS Macro Language are 'free format' giving the ability to format and indent code for better readability. When compiling a macro, the SAS Macro Facility strips out any formatting (spaces, line breaks, tabs, etc.) in the model text to minimize the size of the stored text.
> DATALINES, CARDS, and PARMCARDS statements are not free format. When the SAS Macro Facility compiles these statements, it removes the formatting, which would very possibly move data into incorrect lines and/or columns. This can cause incorrect results and is the fundamental reason for the restriction.

Comment: Why bring up the restriction on using CARDS in a macro? The question did not even mention anything about macros.